# Sending mail using terminal

Tags: shell, networking, sendmail

So i have Linux Mint 20.1 and i'm trying to send mail using command line. Precisely, first off i tried with mail command:

```
mail -s "someSubject" "someMail@gmail.com" < fileToSend.txt
```

However that didn't work out at all, instead of command execution, i got a terminal with %gt (>). Which, as far as i can tell, means that my command isn't complete. I googled it and it seemed like all i needed to do is to type in EOF, but that didn't work out, since that "new terminal" remained. I tried to check out /var/log/mail.log but i couldn't find anything there.

Next thing i tried is sendmail command:

```
sendmail someMail@gmail.com < fileToSend.txt
```

This executes just fine (no errors or something), however, i still couldn't receive that mail so i had to check out that log file again. This time it said the following:

```
gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com(corresponding IPv4 address and port was here): Connection timed out
```

and

```
alt1.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com(corresponding IPv6 address and port was here): Network is unreachable
```

I checked for my default gateway and it's address corresponds to local address of my router so that's fine.

When i try to ping above mentioned IPV4 address it worked out just fine. However, when i tried to ping above mentioned IPv6 address:

```
ping6 -c 4 -I wlp3s0 (IPv6 address here)
```

it says that it is unreachable.

Any help with this would be appreciated!

Comment: Try that first command again, and be sure that you type all quotes.  Getting the secondary prompt indicates that you somehow forgot one of the quotes, or used mismatched double/single quotes, or "typographical" (fancy) quotes.

Comment: @Kusalananda I've tried the first command again, this time it worked just fine, meaning the command itself executed but still mail wasn't sent and when i read through log file i have the same problem i had when i tried to send mail via sendmail command, as i described in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Often port 25 (outbound) will be blocked by your ISP. You can test this by using `telnet`:

```
$ telnet gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com 25
```

A successful connection looks like:

```
Trying 74.125.68.26...
Connected to gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 mx.google.com ESMTP y22si1641751pll.208 - gsmtp
```

If port 25 is blocked, you'll see:

```
Trying 2607:f8b0:400e:c06::1a...
Trying 74.125.195.27...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection timed out
```

---

If port 25 is blocked, then you'll either want to contact your ISP or use an [SMTP relay](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/postfix-smtp-relay-ubuntu-sendinblue) (I use mailjet.com).

ISPs will often block port 25 because if you start sending spam (or get a virus who sends spam), then your IP address could get black-listed.  In some cases an entire IP block could get black listed.  ISPs don't want their IP blocks to appear on email blacklists so they restrict their users from sending emails on port 25.

---

If it's not blocked, then it's probably a problem with your configuration.  This is a longer subject that requires a full guide.  I used [setup-basic-postfix-mail-sever-ubuntu](https://www.linuxbabe.com/mail-server/setup-basic-postfix-mail-sever-ubuntu) successfully.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried telnet as you suggested but it turns out that connection is timed out, however, i am not sure if that means that port 25 is blocked because when i run nmap -sT localhost it says that smtp service is open (tcp port 25).

Comment: `nmap -sT <your-public-ip-or-domain>` checks if your machine is listening on port 25 (inbound).  i.e:  It's checking port 25 inbound only.  This affects your ability to receive emails, but does not tell you whether you can send emails (port 25 outbound).  Furthermore: `nmap -sT localhost` only tells you if your machine is listening on those ports on the local network. It does not test if your ISP, or your router's firewall is blocking anything.  If the `telnet` connection is timed out, then port 25 (outbound) is blocked by your ISP.